# map built from string value extraction - cannot recover value

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm currently trying to manipulate a map in groovy but I'm facing a problem that I can't work out.

I build a map in order to have an id as key and a name as value
I have to store it as a string, then recover it and rebuild the map. 
My keys look like id:my:device, names look like

When I build my map, I end up having something like
mymap = [id:my:device: ...etc.] which does not cause any problem for recovery, mymap[id:my:device] gives my device name.

**EDIT** : 
I build the map doing `name_uid_map[measure.uid] =jSonResponse.value` for every map element and, at the end of my testCase, I store it doing `testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("name_uid_map", name_uid_map.toString()`

After storage and recovery, as it is stored as a string, it becomes uneasy to decypher. I modify the string in order to have "id:my:device"='my device name', then I rebuild the map doing the following (otherwise it splits from the first ':')

```
mymap = map.split(",\\s*").collectEntries{
    def keyAndVal = it.split("=")
    [(keyAndVal[0]):keyAndVal[1]]
}
```

The problem is now my rebuilt map looks like 
{"id:my:device"='my device name' ... }
If I do

```
mymap.each{
key, value -> 
    log.info key
    log.info value
```

}

I obtain 
key : "id:my:device"
value : my device name
which is correct. When I want to recover value from the key, I encounter my problem, ie:

```
mymap["id:my:device"] = null
```

If I try to get the type of the value I get :

```
my value = class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject
```

I'm not easy at all with handling maps in groovy and I'm sure I've done something wrong, but I can't figure it out, could someone help me ?

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 
Actually I found another way to fulfill my needs

In the testStep where I build my initial map I do the following:
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
and I store my map in a custom property like this, to make sure it's a valid JSON

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("name_uid_map", new JsonBuilder(name_uid_map).toString())
```

In the next testStep, I do the following (simple extraction of JSON):

```
def name_uid_map = context.expand( '${#TestCase#name_uid_map}' )
def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()

map = jsonSlurper.parseText(name_uid_map)
```

and it works fine.